# Example of a connected Riemannian manifold containing a non-compact closed bounded set

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry

What is an example of a connected Riemannian manifold containing a non-compact closed bounded set?

By the Hopf-Rinow Theorem, I know that the closed bounded sets of a connected Riemannian manifold are compact if and only if the manifold is complete. So I have to pick a non complete Riemannian manifold. Let's say I choose the punctured sphere or an open hemisphere with the induced metric from Euclidean space. "Where is" that closed bounded subset of the sphere which is not compact? Or am I in the wrong track?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In any metric space, if $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence which does not converge, then the subset $\{x_n\}$ is closed, bounded, and not compact.  Alternatively, if your entire manifold is bounded (as in the examples you name), you can just take the closed bounded set to be the entire manifold.

Comment: Thank you! I was just trying to figure out why the subset $\{x_n\}$ of a  non convergent Cauchy sequence has to be closed. Can't it have more than one accumulation point?

Comment: Nope, if a Cauchy sequence accumulates at a point, it must converge to that point.  For if you can choose some very large $N$ such that $x_N$ is close to $p$, then $x_n$ will be close to $p$ for all $n>N$ as well since the sequence is Cauchy.

Answer (score 5):

Take the open unit disk in the plane. It is closed in itself but not compact.

Comment: Or more intuitively (but not really) any diagonal that runs across it. It wont be compact as the endpoints are missing! This uses the fact that compactness is intrinsic and a segment missing endpoints is not compact either as a subset of plane or as a subset of part of plane.